# Bulk operation on GET

Tags: api-design

What would be the best way to design an API to accept a request for a bulk GET. I currently have a scenario where I have about 100 id's. I don't want to call the API 100 times to get each resource but sending 100 GUIDs in a Query String doesn't seem right either.

What is the proper way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have too much specific parameters, it is common way to use POST with JSON body, where you specify, what you want.

But having big query string is not bad either (just remember there is limitation for maximum length). You can have even array in query string, it is sended (and consumed) as this : `http://something.com?ids[0]=7&ids[1]=33&ids[2]=5`

Frameworks (like Spring) are able to automatically convert these parameters into arrays or lists.

Comment: I didn't want to use POST because that implies I am changing something and I could use GET and expand the accepted query string length on my server to accommodate, it just seemed cluttered but I can't think of any other approach to take.

Comment: How I said, using a large string query is fine too. Send 100 GUIDs in query string as array is fine. For example if you use "advanced search" in google, you get this : `https://www.google.cz/search?hl=cs&as_q=geeg&as_epq=aegeg&as_oq=ybcvb&as_eq=aegage&as_nlo=10&as_nhi=50&lr=lang_en&cr=countryEC&as_qdr=m&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=body&safe=images&as_filetype=pdf&as_rights=%28cc_publicdomain%7Ccc_attribute%7Ccc_sharealike%7Ccc_noncommercial%7Ccc_nonderived%29`